# Subordinate projections: Transitivity

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra. If necessary, let us assume that $A$ is a von Neumann algebra. For projections $p,q \in A$ one writes $p \prec q$ if $p$ is Murray-von Neumann-equivalent to a subprojection of $q$, i.e. there is a partial isometry $u \in A$ such that $u^* u = p$ and $u u^* \leq q$. One also says that $p$ is subordinate to $q$.

Why is $\prec$ a transitive relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $p\prec q\prec r$. That is, there exist projections $q_0\leq q$ and $r_0\leq r$ with partial isometries $u,v$ with $u^*u=p$, $uu^*=q_0$, $v^*v=q$, $vv^*=r_0$.

Note that $u=up=q_0u$ and $v=r_0v=vq$.

Let $w=vu$. Then 
$$
w^*w=u^*v^*vu=u^*qu=u^*qq_0u=u^*q_0u=u^*u=p,
$$
and
$$
ww^*=vuu^*v^*=vq_0v^*\leq vv^*=r_0\leq r.
$$
So $p\prec r$.

Comment: Thank you! First, I thought that one has to verify that $w$ is a partial isometry. But this follows since $w^* w=p$ is a projection. It is superfluous to assume partial isometries in the definition of $\prec$, right?

Comment: It is. Note that in an algebraic setting, the only natural meaning of "partial isometry" is "$v^*v$ and $vv^*$ projections"; and just one of them implies the other. If we are talking operators on a Hilbert space, then $v^*v$ or $vv^*$ projection implies that $v$ is a partial isometry.

Comment: I think a better definition is $v v^* v  = v$. This then also works in $*$-algebras which are no $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: Good point. That would make a difference in $*$-algebras where there exist nonzero elements $a$ with $a^*a=0$. Is there a significant such example?

Comment: I suggest $*$-algebras with a $C^*$-seminorm.